# not able to locate entry point for a method in dll?

Tags: c++, dll

Hi I have a class and I wrote few methods in it. Then I created dll for that class. Now i commented out few methods and then again created dll for the class. But now when i am loading the dll in one of the exe I get  the error poped out like this,"NOt able to locate entry point for abc method in xyz dll".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recompile the exe?

If not, then please, recompile it, because something has changed in the DLL API.

If yes, then you probably are linking with the old LIB file instead of the new one, and something has changed in the DLL API.